# How to configure testNG in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automated-tests, testng

I have a testNG project running on Eclipse with the nestNG plug-in, but I want to configure the pom.xml to be able to run in on IntelliJ as well.

I tryed to use the same version of testNG that appears on Dependency Hierarchy but I am having some problems with these imports:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.reporters.Files;
```

Can someone help me with witch dependencies I need to import in my pom.xml to use IntelliJ IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Read IntelliJ documentation.
This should solve most of your issues:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/testng.html#testng-test-suites

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I enabled testNG plugin in File -> Settings -> Plugins and restarted IntelliJ IDE.